Unsupported operating system [MINGW64_NT-10.0-19045]. Laravel Sail supports macOS, Linux, and Windows (WSL2)
I was trying to clone this repository: https://github.com/aliaxonbaig/quizapp , it's a laravel project about an application to manage quiz, now I have a problem when entering the "sail up -d" command, I get the following error: Unsupported operating system [MINGW64_NT-10.0-19045]. Laravel Sail supports macOS, Linux, and Windows (WSL2). How can I solve this?
I tried running the same command from a wsl terminal with Ubuntu, but I didn't have good results, it gave me the following error:
./.env: line 6: $'\r': command not found
./.env: line 10: $'\r': command not found
./.env: line 17: $'\r': command not found
./.env: line 24: $'\r': command not found
./.env: line 26: $'\r': command not found
./.env: line 30: $'\r': command not found
./.env: line 39: $'\r': command not found
./.env: line 45: $'\r': command not found
./.env: line 53: $'\r': command not found
Docker is not running.
How can I solve this?

This is not directly telling you how to use Sail as it would be far more difficult and longer than the solution I will propose for you here.
Laravel Herd recently released on Windows which does a similar job to Laravel Sail but is far easier to get it configured and ready to go.
Install Laravel Herd from it's official site: Laravel Herd
then download the repository and place it in folder where Herd is configured to serve sites from: Serving Sites
You can then continue with the installation instructions but remove any Sail related functionality.
cp .env.example .env
composer install
npm install
npm run build
artisan migrate:fresh
artisan make:filament-user
artisan db:seed
artisan shield:super-admin
artisan db:seed --class ShieldSeeder
npm run dev # Watches for changes and Builds CSS&JS 

Everything should work as normal now and you won't have the added extra complexity that would have been present due to Sail usage.
